# Split Date Range into Weeks in Excel document and populate values

Tags: excel

How are you doing!
I have a requirement where I have a date range, total number of hrs. I want to split this date range into weeks, with each week as a column in excel document and the total hrs split equally

For example, 
My date range is 10/03/2016 to 10/30/2016, and total hours as 100
Now, this date range consists of 4 weeks

So, in my excel, I want to automatically label 4 columns, with value in each = 100/4 = 25

Like the image below
[image: Excel file with Rows 6 & 7 auto generated based on Row 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Hello Dirk, I'm very new to excel. I could calculate the number of weeks by using the formula DATEDIF, but that's it. What I want is to have so many columns with labels week1, week2, ...., weekx. I guess we need to use some sort of function here to loop through till the number of weeks, but have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Use something like `=ROUNDUP((DATEDIF(B1,B2,"d")/7),0)` to get the number of weeks. From there you could either use VBA macros (if you have lot of columns) OR just copy-paste one formula into successive cells (that have a formula to keep track of "how many days still left". You stop copy-pasting when you run out of days, and left with zero days).